# Find and replace only specific characters in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

An example of what I want to do.. I have tons of:

```
name : 'SomethingXX',
```

I want to become:

```
name: 'Something Else',
```

Where `Something` is different for every entry, so I can find all using `name : '((.*?))XX'`

But then to replace I need to be able to keep the `Something` but change the `XX` and don't know how to do that. I can't just find replace the XX because it appears at other places also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace XX with what you want in all lines:

```
^name : '.+?\KXX
```

- find: `^name : '.+?\KXX`
- Replace: `What you want`

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  name : '  : literally
  .+?       : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  XX        : XX (what to be changed)
```